# When drawing an arbitrary point in an image, how to find the coordinates of the two closest lines perpendicular to that point?

Tags: python, image, opencv, coordinates, detect

[image]

I draw an arbitrary point in this image.

I want to find the coordinates of the two lines closest to this point.

**It should be a straight line when you connect one of the two points to any point.**

Like this :

[image]

> **I want to know two thing**
>
> - **First, Is there a library to find the nearest line from  an arbitrary point?**
> - **Second, Is there any library or algorithm to find a point perpendicular to an arbitrary point?**

Please help me.....

Comment: distance transform. watershed possibly. something along those lines. -- or throw all the coordinates into a FLANN and do a lookup. -- consider whether you mean "perpendicular" or "closest". for straight lines, that's the same. your lines aren't straight.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two steps: first for the closest line, then for the other one.

- **The closest line**:
  Let **A** be the arbitrary point.
  You can calculate the distance of each white pixel to point **A** and keep the shortest distance **(sqrt((x-a.x)^2 + (y-a.y)^2)**. This closest pixel (let's call it **P**) is the projected point on the line. By definition of the projected point, the line **AP** is perpendicular to the line.
- **The other line**: color all the points of the closest line so as not to search again in its pixels, do the same thing as for the closest line.